# AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Recently I started working on VS2010 and I am referencing AjaxControlToolkit 4.1.51116.0.
I am getting below runtime error -

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET
>   Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are
>   referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the
>   ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

I have seen many question floating for same error but the solution suggested is to use `'ToolkitScriptManager'` instead of `'ScriptManager'` is not working for me. 
Any help in this context would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you replace the `<asp:ScriptManager />` tag with the namespace of your `AjaxControlToolkit` assembly (e.g. `atk`): `<atk:ToolkitScriptManager />`. That worked for me.

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>


<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

Not working, why?

Comment: @LucasRodriguesSena I recommend you ask your own question

Comment: <asp:ScriptManager /> tag is supposed to be supported Ajax 4.0 - .net4.0/.net4.5, since it is not working there appears to be some sort of configuration issue.  Reverting to <atk:ToolkitScriptManager /> is not the fix to the config problem. There are a number of posts appearing reporting this same issue. Apparently as more developers move to VS2012.