# Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am getting this error when I attempt to run my aspx application even though I am in 3.5 framework.

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.**

I search SO and tried the solution in [this post ("AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862280/ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts)"), but I am still getting the error. I tried the solution here [AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982236/ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts-ensure-the-correct-version), but no luck.

I am using VS 2008 SP 1. In my refrences folder, the AjaxControlToolkit is version "3.5.50401.0" Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous posts, you may have an UpdatePanel control. Make sure you don't have an updatepanel control. They don't work well with Telerik controls (based on my experience).

Answer (score 0):

Refer this site and download new toolkit, [Link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Download.ashx)

I think you might have copy pasted the code from some other site which was developed with APS.net 4.0 framework with latest ajax toolkit, download and install "Ajax Control Toolkit" and you are done with the problem.

I hope this will do.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include the “ToolkitScriptManager” rather than the standard “ScriptManager”.To add the ToolkitScriptManager, you first need to include the assembly namespace on your aspx page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Then you can simply include the manager and change the standard script manager

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMaster" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

to this:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkitScriptMaster" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

You can refer these links for Reference

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862280/ajaxcontroltoolkit-requires-asp-net-ajax-4-0-scripts)
[Link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1529516.aspx)

Hope it helps you